# Submit onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to code a post form which sends the form to another window and then reloads the window in which the form was submitted in.
page2 is not on the same domain as page1 and i can't access the code of page2.

My current form on page1 looks like this:

```html
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="https://www.page2.com">
<input type="hidden" name="input1" value="input1value">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function1();window.location.refresh()">
</form>
```

The form is being send successfully and the function is being executed but the tab won't refresh.

Comment: That's because the order of events is: 1) tell window to reload, 2) form submits, overriding the reload action.

Comment: so how am i able to solve this? i tried to add an input type button and add an EventListener that reloads the page first and then submits the form but it's not working.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what functionality you want to happen. So, when someone clicks your submit button, what is suppose to happen? The page reloads? When a form is submitted the browser `POST`s or `GET`s based on the form's set `method` attribute to a new page, and displays the response. You could, in the response, have some sort of code to reload/redirect the page?

Comment: My form is on page1 and it opens page2 in a new tab. I need page1 to get refreshed and it doesn't matter if it happens before the new tab is loaded or after.

Comment: How is the form opening a page in a new tab?

Comment: Is it using `target="_blank"` in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: yeah the target is _blank

Comment: What does “send the form to another window” mean? What would a new window do with form data? What is the goal of this?

Comment: the data is just being send to another domain which doesn't interact with my code at all. but i want to update a message on my page which depends on a cookie, that's why i need a single page refresh.

Comment: try to use ajax and inside of the `success` type the location reload, this will wait until the information is sent but you will need also to handle the error to redirect in case your server didn't work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="https://www.page2.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="input1" value="input1value">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"onclick="window.location.reload();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

While your use case is not obvious at the moment, this might be useful.
Handle submit using script, prevent the default action, post the form and then reload the page.

```
<form id="myForm" target="_blank"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="wait(event);" >
</form>
```

script

```
function wait(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
 console.log('done!')
 window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: it just refreshes my page but the form is not being send :/

Comment: is it opening the new window/tab to submit the form ? Are you allowed to use `jquery` ? Can you also share the `form` in the question ? Remove any info that you do not want to share. Just want to see the action and target.

Answer (score 0):

try this code this will refresh you page 1.

```js
     function function_one(){
      $.ajax({
       url: 'show.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {'value': $("#input1").val()},
       
       success: function(data){
        
        window.location.refresh();
       }
      });
     }
```

```html
 
  <form target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="input1value" id="input1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function_one()">
    
    </form>
    <p id="asfasf"></p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```